# while upgrading to spring boot 2.0, getting UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: spring-boot

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mobimed.team' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    ... 95 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1

Actually, the table is existing in the db

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Teams")
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
public class Team implements Serializable
```

After Spring Boot 2.0 migration: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName when I got this error, I have used this to resolve 
app.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test 
now, I'm getting the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the annotation @Table I can see you have named your BD table `Teams` and Spring is trying to get a `Team` database and fails for that reason. I am guessing that you have some queries that refer to incorrect table name

Comment: Thanks for the note!

yes, I have been using hibernate query
@Query(value = "SELECT T.name FROM Team T WHERE T.id = :id")
and this was working fine with Spring Boot 1.5

Comment: So the table name in your BD is actually `Team` or `Teams`?

Comment: it is Teams in the DB

Comment: ok cool, in that case just try editing the existing query to select the correct table:
@Query(value = "SELECT T.name FROM Teams T WHERE T.id = :id")

Comment: hey, Thanks for asking that, actually one of the queries I modified it to nativeQuery and still using Team. it's working now! Thanks again!